# Is there a way to say that "you weren't somewhere for some time that wasn't enough to do sth"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

If somebody asks:

> A) Could you do your homework last night/on the weekend?

The following response seems wrong, but I don't know what the right answer is!

> B) No. I wasn't home enough (which means I needed 2 hours to do them
>   but I was home only for 30 minutes)

Can you please share a correct response with "enough" in it?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It seems appropriate to me for this site...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "enough" in your sentence, then you can say:

> I wasn't home **long enough** to do my homework.

or

> I didn't have **enough time** to do my homework. *(I'd probably express the idea like this)*

Alternatively, you might say:

> I was **pressed for time**, and so I didn't do my homework.
>
> I was **short of time**, and so I didn't do my homework.
>
> I **didn't have time** to do my homework.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest sentence that fits your conditions is "No, I didn't have **enough time** at home". You could also you use "No, I wasn't at home for long **enough**". (Though this is fairly idiomatic)

While your sentence would probably be understood by most native speakers (though "**at** home" would make it clearer), what you are actually trying to emphasise is that you were limited in time, hence making it clear this what you didn't have "enough" of.